# How to specify the value of the first tick in a graph using ggplot2 without changing the origin value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, xticks

Here is my data:

```
X,Y
0,725
2500,695
4750,629
5000,605
5500,598
7000,616
8500,594
0,725
2250,695
4750,629
6500,640
9750,647
0,725
2250,695
4750,629
6500,640
10000,680
```

Here is my current code (excluding a bunch of geom_segments needed for this graph):

```
ggplot(sb, aes(x= X,y= Y)) +
  labs(x = "\nDistance in Feet", y = "Feet Above Mean Sea Level\n") + #\n allows for a line break
  geom_line(color = "orange") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 800, by = 50), lim = c(0,800), expand = c(0, 0))  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10000, by = 1000), lim = c(0,12000), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Calibri"))  #change font
```

Here is the graph that populates just the code I posted (without the geom_line segments):
[image]

What I would like is to keep the origin at 0,0 but have the first tick of the y-axis to start at a value of 200 instead of having it start at 50. But I would like to keep the ticks in increments of 50 ending at 800. So the first tick would be 200, then 250 etc to 800. I have tried setting the limits from lim = c(0,800) to lim = c(200,800) but that just had 200 be the origin instead of 0. I want to keep 0 as the origin. The graph is a cross section of a soil boring underground that ends around 200 so the area under the 200 value mark is just empty space once I add in the vertical lines. I can add the graph with all the geom_lines if it helps you visualize it more. Thanks!

Comment: Change your `breaks` for the y-axis: `breaks = seq(200, 800, by = 50)`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

### Change scale to y-axis

You can do that by changing the `scale_y_continuous` `breaks` like this:

```
... +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, seq(200, 800, by = 50)), lim = c(0,800), expand = c(0, 0))  +
...
```

Your plot will look like this:

[image]

Complete final code:

```
ggplot(sb, aes(x= X,y= Y)) +
  labs(x = "\nDistance in Feet", y = "Feet Above Mean Sea Level\n") + #\n allows for a line break
  geom_line(color = "orange") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, seq(200, 800, by = 50)), lim = c(0,800), expand = c(0, 0))  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10000, by = 1000), lim = c(0,12000), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Calibri"))  #change font
```

Hope this helps.